# Unattended DCPromo creating new domain fails as user is not domain admin

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2003, domain-controller, dcpromo

I have installed Windows Server 2003 and am trying to make it a DC on a new domain.

It works ok if I use the wizard, but when I try to use an answer file, it says 'An AD domain controller for the domain MYPCNAME could not be contacted'

The error message is true as there is no AD domain yet, that's what I'm trying to create!

My answer file (based on https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758390(v=ws.10).aspx) is:

```
[DCINSTALL]
UserName=MyLocalAdmin
UserDomain=MYPCNAME
Password=mYpa55word
ReplicaDomainDNSName=ABC-DEF.group.org
ReplicaOrNewDomain=Domain
InstallDNS=Yes
ConfirmGC=Yes
RebootOnCompletion=NoAndNoPromptEither
```

I've tried with 'ReplicaOrNewDomain=newDomain' as well, but that was no different. It doesn't get beyond asking for network credentials, even though I'm running this as a local admin.

There is no existing DNS, I want this PC to become a DNS server
Any ideas (and please, no comments about using ancient OSs!)

Comment: Just FYI, you're likely to get some comments about the fact that Windows Server 2003 is no longer in support - and as such is likely going to be regarded as being off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're using an ancient, unsupported OS.  this is borderline off-topic here.
2. Your answer file is completely incorrect for a new domain.  where did you get these settings?

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/223757

**Unattended promotion and demotion of Windows 2000 and Windows Server 2003 domain controllers**

For new tree in new forest installations, the following options apply:

```
[DCINSTALL]
ReplicaOrNewDomain=Domain
TreeOrChild=Tree
CreateOrJoin=Create
NewDomainDNSName=<fully qualified DNS domain name (for example, corp.com) >
DNSOnNetwork=yes
DomainNetbiosName=<NetBIOS domain name>
AutoConfigDNS=yes
SiteName=[active directory site name (optional)];
AllowAnonymousAccess=no
DatabasePath=%systemroot%\ntds
LogPath=%systemroot%\ntds
SYSVOLPath=%systemroot%\sysvol
SafeModeAdminPassword=<admin defined offline admin account password>
CriticalReplicationOnly=No
RebootOnSuccess=yes
```

Answer (score -1):

That message errs on DNS-resolving. It tries to locate the 'MYPCNAME.ABC-DEF.GROUP.ORG' domain based on the [SRV-record of an existing Active Directory-integrated DNS-server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc759550(v=ws.10).aspx#w2k3tr_addns_how_nsbm).

Comment: Yes, but that's the domain I'm trying to create. That's what I didn't understand. @Bluecompute has been able to point me to the answer. Looks like I started with a bit of duff information.